# fishshell unsuspend emacs frame %emacs command

Tags: bash, emacs, fish

There is command to suspend current frame `suspend-frame`, and it works perfectly to pause current emacsclient in terminal returning to shell. To get current frame back you can type in bash `%emacs`. In fish however such command does not exists or fish knows nothing what I want to do. Is there some way to invoke `%emacs` in fish?

Answer (score 0):

In bash `%emacs` is shorthand for `fg %emacs`. The latter works in fish but I don't recommend it because the expansion of `%emacs` could be ambiguous (i.e., match more than one process). Better to just type `fg` to resume the most recently suspended command. Or type `jobs` to find the relevant job number and explicitly resume it; e.g., `fg %2`.